# \n doesn't work on excel-cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have got a problem to create new lines into a cell. When I create a file, the new lines aren't shown in correct way. I hope someone can help me to solve this issue.

```
    cell.setCellValue(text);
if(text.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator")) != -1)
{
    int countRows = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length;
    style.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    row.setHeightInPoints((countRows * sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
    sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) countRows);
}
```

This is my Excel-File

[image]

When I make a new Excel-File, all the cells are looking like cell A1. There isn't a new line. When I click on the cell A1 shows the description over the cell the content with the new lines.

I made a double click in cell A2 and the cell is showing the content in the correct way.

The new line tag seems to work. My issue is, that the new line isn't shown at the cell in the excel file. But it is shown at the cell description. Is there a way to show all of the cells like the cell A2 without a double click?

Thanks

Comment: Newline character sequence on Windows OS/programs is `\r\n`.

Comment: are you using apache-poi ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using apache-poi. And \r\n isn't working too.Maybe my excel has wrong settings and that's why it's showing wrong?

Comment: could you add more code ? where you are setting data to cell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me ,

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    row.setHeight((short) (2*sheet.getDefaultRowHeight()));
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
    cell.setCellValue(
    createHelper.createRichTextString("This is \n a string"));
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

`\n` should be `\r\n` for excel files.